# Let $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that: $\exists_{M\in\mathbb{R}^+} \forall_{z\in\mathbb{C}}\ \ \ \ |f(z)|> M \Rightarrow f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that: $\exists_{M\in\mathbb{R}^+} \forall_{z\in\mathbb{C}}\ \ \ \  |f(z)|> M \Rightarrow |f(z)|> M \Rightarrow f$ is constant

Completely don't know how to bite that, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about non-constant entire functions? Can their range exclude an interval?

Comment: Your title and your first line don't match up. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What can you say about $g = 1/f$?

Comment: Hmm, can I say that $|g|=\frac{1}{|f|}\leq \frac{1}{M}$ and then use Liouville's theorem to conclude that $g$ must be constant and thus $f$ must be constant? But I don't know if $g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @Mateusz Yes you do. $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ by assumption.

Comment: Ahh, so what I wrote is enough then?